# How to create multi output files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I would like to bundle my chrome extension with Webpack. The source consists multiple entries and the content of the `webpack.config.js` looks as follows:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    actions: './src/actions/index.js',
    options: './src/options/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  }
};
```

And folder structure:
[image]

The `actions/index.js` and `options/index.js` files are entries.
My goal is, when the `src` get bundled then `dist` folder should looks as follows:

[image]

How to configure the webpack config to get the desired folder structure above?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should solve your problems ;)

**file structure**

```
src
├── actions
│   ├── index.html
│   └── index.js
└── options
    ├── index.html
    └── index.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    actions: './src/actions/index.js',
    options: './src/options/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name]/index.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/actions/index.html',
      filename: 'actions/index.html',
      chunks: ['actions']
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/options/index.html',
      filename: 'options/index.html',
      chunks: ['options']
    })
  ]
};
```

**And a more correct version ;)**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const ENTRY = {
  actions: './src/actions/index.js',
  options: './src/options/index.js'
}

const entryHtmlPlugins = Object.keys(ENTRY).map(entryName => {
  return new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: `./src/${entryName}/index.html`,
    filename: `${entryName}/index.html`,
    chunks: [entryName]
  });
});

module.exports = {
  entry: ENTRY,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name]/index.js'
  },
  plugins: entryHtmlPlugins
};
```

I created a branch on github [many-outputs](https://github.com/tomik23/webpack-babel-corejs/tree/many-outputs)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the output path for each entry, this will copy the `js` files into the structure you want.

In order to generate `html` file for each entry, you can use 2 times `HTMLWebpackPlugin` with specifying `chunk` option.

Don't forget to put a `src/options.html` & `src/actions.html` html files as a templates.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'actions/index': './src/actions/index.js',
    'options/index': './src/options/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'options.html'),
      filename: 'options.html',
      chunks: ['options'],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'actions.html'),
      filename: 'actions.html',
      chunks: ['actions'],
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: The content of the `src` folder does not get copied and I've got the error message `Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename index.js (chunks actions/index and options/index)` .

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation of Webpack, you could do something like this (I've done this and it works)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js',
    search: './src/search.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
  },
};
```

***Reference:***
[Multiple entry points webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#multiple-entry-points)