# Webpack4: how to use regular expressoin in HtmlWebPackPlugin configure to generate output for multi-file

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

Currently, I use many configs with the same pattern. I think there must be a better way to do this in one config by using regex.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60590858/10424385)

Comment: @Grizegorz I got your idea -- you are using the Js trick. That makes sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create multi output files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589413/how-to-create-multi-output-files)